# Stream Post URL Security Migration

Tags: security, url, post, stream, rule

I want to know
if the Stream Post URL Security Migration will be just an option or it will be a rule?
Because i want to post links with thumbnails and when i tried to enable it, cannot post with thubmnails.

Can someone help me?
Please!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable/disable it in your app's advanced settings. Go to your app's `dashboard settings > Advanced > Migrations` to set it.

Comment: But I'll be able to Always  enable or disable it or later it will be Always enable?

Comment: @CamileLastLine as far as I can tell, it seems like you can change it. Consider adding more tags to your post like [Facebook] for example.